# Finding positive solution for a system of linear equations using column basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a binary matrix $A$ of size $m\times n$ where $n \gg m$, finding a non-negative $x$ for $Ax=b$ is not feasible, a different approach which I am currently exploring is finding solution for a column basis of this matrix. If there are multiple column basis $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_n$. I am finding a basis $B$ such that solving $Bx=b$ will give a non-negative $x$. I already know that $Ax=b$ has a non-negative $x$.

I am able to find a column basis for all matrices that I have, for which there is a non-negative $x$. Is there any formal proof for this?

**Formally I want to prove that if $Ax=b$ has a non-negative solution then there exists a column basis $B$ such that solving $Bx=b$ will result in non-negative $x$.**